# Gitlab runner: Use own (exiting) docker container

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I registred a runner with

```
sudo gitlab-ci-multi-runner register
```

Executor is set to **docker**

Now I'm asked for the image and I choose *ubuntu:16.04*

But I would like to use a own container, which I have prepared like I need it. How can I use a custom container, which is already existing?

```
docker ps

4109775ba06f    ubuntu:16.04  "/bin/bash"   25 minutes ago   Up 21 minutes  want_this_one
```

Comment: A container and an image is not the same thing. You can commit your container to turn it into an image though. Pass that image to gitlab and that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitlab CI cannot use an already running container. The way to go for this is to build an image the way you want on the machine hosting your runners.

For instance, write a Dockerfile with all the steps needed to build your custom image:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# do all the custom steps here
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install - yq ...
```

Then build your image with

```
docker build -t custom_image .
```

Another way is to commit your already existing container to an image like this

```
docker commit 4109775ba06f custom_image
```

Finally in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` use your newly built image:

```
image: custom_image
```